# DataGridView don't display all records

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, ado.net

DataGridViewImageColumn do not display all records.
I have a datagridview that is to display all records.
But this is not happening!
Only those records that have a picture in a field (say - "Photo").
And those records that do not have the image is not displayed.
Why is this happening?
That I have not tried all else fails.
Try this:

```
            Load += delegate
        { 
            foreach (var column in dataGridView1.Columns)
            {
                if (column is DataGridViewImageColumn)
                    (column as DataGridViewImageColumn).DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
            }
        };
```

and this:

```
   var column1 = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
   column1.DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = null;
   column1.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewEmptyImageCell();

    private class DataGridViewEmptyImageCell : DataGridViewImageCell
    {
        public override object DefaultNewRowValue { get { return null; } }
    }
```

Insert after `InitializeComponent()` and  in `private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e);`
Add code about this theme:
Class Connection have this method:

```
        public void FillDataGridView(DataGridView dataGridView, string query="")
     {
         try
         {
             command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection); //Создаём запрос для поиска
             adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command); //Выполняем команду
             //Для отображения в таблице
             DataTable table = new DataTable(); //Создаём таблицу
             adapter.Fill(table); //Вставляем данные при выполнении команды в таблицу
             dataGridView.DataSource = table; //подключаем заполненную таблицу и отображаем
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
         }
     }
```

Code in Form which have DataGridView:

```
        private void TestFormTwo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillDataGridView("");
    }

    public void FillDataGridView(string valueToSearch)
    {
        //получаем запрос на отображение данных с поиском
        string nameTable = "info";
        string[] nameFieldsAll = {"id_info", "full_name", "passport_id", "age", "address", "phone", "photo"};
        string[] nameFieldsAS = {"ИД","ФИО","Серия и номер паспорта","Возраст","Адрес","Телефон","Фото"};
        string[] numericFields = {"id_info","age"};
        string query = connection.GetQueryShowSearch(nameTable, nameFieldsAll, nameFieldsAS, numericFields, valueToSearch);
        //заполняем данные таблицы на основе запроса
        connection.FillDataGridView(dataGridView1, query);
        settings.GetSettingDisplayTable(dataGridView1, 100);
        settings.GetViewImageInCellTable(dataGridView1, 6);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I checked datagridview shows rows with imageColumn even if image is null and if cell style is set to null.
If you have debugged your code and  you are sure that those rows are really in datasource of your dataGrid then there has to be some bug in your code or something in your datagridview properties is set incorrectly. 
Please, post some more code (runnable preferred) so we can check it out.

Comment: Please, look at code. I'm added more code for check it out